# Specify number of digits for IO[Float] scala

Tags: scala, io, floating-point, precision, cats-effect

I want to read a float, check the type provided by the user, identify number of digits which is fixed at  two digits. For this :

I ve implemented these three functions. The first that reads the input from the console:

```
  def readFloat: IO[Float] = IO {
    scala.io.StdIn.readFloat()
  }
```

Another function that checks whether the input is a Float or not :

```
def findDataType(x: Any): IO[Unit] = x match {
    case x: Int =>
      IO(println("Integer identified, provide a Float with 2 digits"))
    case x: Float => IO(println("Float identified, Thanks"))
    case _ =>
      IO(println("DataType not identified, , provide a Float with 2 digits"))
  }
```

and the third one that checks the number of digits:

```
 def valueWith2digits(v: Float): Boolean = {
    val comp = BigDecimal(v)
      .setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)
      .toFloat
    if (v.toFloat == comp) true else false
  }
```

The function takes a Float but I have IO[Float]. I could not figure out how to unwrap the provided value in order to check if 2 digits were given or not.
How can I fix this

Comment: What `IO` are you using? `cats.effect.IO`? It's not `zio.IO` (wrong number of type parameters).

Comment: It is cats effect  IO